# How can I group selected data by date (timestamp)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to count entries grouped by date (field has `TIMESTAMP` type in database).
I wrote code

```rb
sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt, TO_CHAR(closed_on, 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS closed_on, issues.status_id
    FROM issues
    WHERE closed_on IS NOT NULL AND closed_on <= '#{end_from_created_date}'
    AND created_on <= '#{end_from_created_date}'
    GROUP BY closed_on, status_id
"
```

This query work on postrgesql, but it does not work on sqlite, because sqlite does not have `TO_CHAR` function
Solution should be compatible with mysql, postgresql, sqlite.

I can use different sql for different DB. But it is not good idea.

May be I can use functions from ActiveRecord, but i do not find solutions in docs

Comment: what error message you get ?

Comment: When I run unit test (using sqlite) I got error "no such function TO_CHAR`

Comment: yes, SQLite dont have `TO_CHAR` function

Comment: `cast(closed_on as date)` maybe? That would be standard SQL to convert a `timestamp` to a `date`. The do the formatting in the frontend when _displaying_ those values.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```rb
sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt, DATE(closed_on) AS closed_on, issues.status_id FROM issues WHERE closed_on IS NOT NULL AND closed_on <= '#{end_from_created_date}' AND created_on <= '#{end_from_created_date}' GROUP BY DATE(closed_on), status_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [several date formats](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); PostgreSQL uses [similar formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) and more.

Both understand YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.